# I need to run a procedure that goes through all schemas tables in MySQL server

Tags: mysql

I am new in creating procedures ,Actually I need to run a **procedure** that will run on all **schemas tables** in my server when am calling the procedure it gives me this error

> ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SET_UTF_ALL_TABLES()
BEGIN

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE a CHAR(150);
DECLARE _counter INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE row_number INT;

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables             
where TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('SCHEMA1','SCHEMA2','SCHEMA3','SCHEMA4') ;

SELECT COUNT(*) from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA IN 
('SCHEMA1','SCHEMA2','SCHEMA3','SCHEMA4') INTO row_number;

OPEN cur1;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

read_loop: LOOP
   FETCH cur1 INTO a;
IF done THEN
    LEAVE read_loop;
END IF;
IF _counter < row_number THEN
    ALTER TABLE a CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
    SET _counter = _counter + 1;
END IF;
END LOOP;

CLOSE cur1;
END;
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: I got it , I need now to loop on each table how could I do that in prepared statment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Selecting `TABLE_NAME` is not enough. You need `CONCAT(TABLE_NAME, '.', TABLE_SCHEMA)`.
2. You cannot use a variable in a query as a place where tablename is stored. You must use dynamic SQL (prepared statement).

[Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

> I need now to loop on each table how could I do that in prepared statement

Get each `database.table` which must be converted. Build proper altering query text in a variable. Prepare. Execute. Iterate next. Repeat until all tables processed. - [akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina)